# Send POST data to payment gateway on form submit

Tags: 6, redirection, forms, payment-gateways

I am running drupal 6 and currently working on payment gateway integration module. I have a basic form in my module which will collect billing information from the user. In the form submit handler, I need to create certain parameters and send the post data to the payment gateway URL. How do I handle this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You payment processor should provide you with example code that shows you how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7).

> Performs an HTTP request.
>
> This is a flexible and powerful HTTP client implementation. Correctly handles GET, POST, PUT or any other HTTP requests. Handles redirects.

Comment: I do not need a response from the payment gateway. I just need to construct post data and send it to the payment gateway.

Comment: yeah, you can do whatever you want. either way, the server will send a response no matter how you connect to it, it's up to you what you're going to do with that response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CURL](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). CURL stands for client URL library. It allows you to communicate with any webservice (and much more). It can handle SSL/HTTPS and all the other stuff you might need.